# Is there a term for contemporary words that historically described a state of affairs that's no longer the case?

Tags: terminology

The example in question: the term "chemist" has been used to describe pharmacists since the middle ages, because in the middle ages and perhaps until a century or so ago, the pharmacist *literally was* the chemist who synthesized the substances you purchased from him. This is no longer the case in any way at all, and yet the term remains in common use to refer to pharmacists.

I can't think of any other distinct examples off the top of my head. "Sinister", maybe? It used to literally described left-handed people because the association between left-handedness and evil was so strong as to be built into the language, and of course, since that association has largely disappeared, the word now only invokes its abstract meaning of "evil".

Edit: so, it seems like the phenomenon in question is kind of like the verbal equivalent of a [skeuomorph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skeuomorph). I wonder if there's a term for that specifically, but I don't see it mentioned in any of the number of similar threads.

Comment: *Chemist* in BrE still means *pharmacist*. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chemist

Comment: Other examples might include *tape* and *film*, two words that have outlived the physical media they originally described, and now describe any audio/video recording regardless of media.

Comment: [Related question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/556511/24129)

Comment: Many (most?) words are like this. For example, “[girl](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED18637/track?counter=1&search_id=5141496)” was a unisex word at one point, with the expression “knave girl” specifying a male child specifically.

Comment: For better or worse, many words are orphaned from their original meaning. They live on, not as vestiges, but as independent words.

Comment: (This is probably a duplicate of any of the many questions that have “semantic shift” as an answer, such as https://english.stackexchange.com/q/92348/191178)

Comment: "Gentleman" used to mean a man who owned land. And don't get me started about dialing a phone number or hanging up when today's smart phone has neither a dial nor a hook on which to hang it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [What is it called when a word no longer literally describes something?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/480217/17956)

Comment: @NuclearHoagie: Or how about "record," which used to mean a vinyl record album. Today, even a CD is called a record. Well, a CD, as with a vinyl record, is a recording. It just happens to be a digital recording, not an analog one.

Comment: Is there such a thing as reverse anachronism?